# .hide is not working on click function

Tags: jquery

Currently, I have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search a').click(function() {
    $('.search2').show();
  });
  $('.search-close').click(function() {
    $('.search2').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search2">
  <form method="get" class="search-form2" id="search-form2" action="search.php">
    <input class="search-input2" type="text" name="search_keywords" id="search-text2" value="" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">
    <a href="#!" class="search-lose"><img src="new_assets/assets/images/closebtn.png"></a>
</div>
```

The purpose oh this is to open a pop-up search box and using a button/image it will close that pop-up

Comment: Please include all relevant html, Since your code should work just fine

Comment: What does the console say (ctrl+shift+i in Chrome) when you try to perform the action? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: You have a TYPO `class="search-lose"` missing `c` in `close`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I think your code is not relevant on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(".search2").hide();
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $(".search2").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>
</body>
<div class="search2">
  <form method="get" class="search-form2" id="search-form2" action="search.php">
    <input class="search-input2" type="text" name="search_keywords" id="search-text2" value="" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">
    <a href="#!" class="search-lose"><img src=""></a>
    </form>
</div>
</html>
```